# Shower Hot Water Pipe (Pex to copper) Pulse/Knock when Off

Tags: plumbing, shower

I've been searching for days trying to find a solution or a similar discussion and haven't come across anything.

The problem I'm having started out of the blue. Been in my house for 3 years without any issues, all of a sudden the other day the master shower started making a knocking noise. It is a recurring noise that continues off and on all day and night. I've cut a hole in the wall and been in the rafters and can feel a "pulsing" in the pex pipe feeding into the wall where the shower fixture is.

It doesn't sound like water hammer at all. When I turn on the hot water it stops and I have no pulsing of water pressure. When I close the valve it sometimes knocks and other times doesn't but within seconds to minutes the recurring pulse comes back.

I'm at a loss as to what to do and any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. To be clear: does this "pulsing" or "knocking" noise happen even when there's no apparent water use in the house? Is there anything water-related that had changed when this started?

Comment: Hi and thanks for the welcome. This happens all throughout the day with no water use going on anywhere on the property. Nothing has been changed in the entire water system which is why this is so confusing, it just started up one day. I originally thought it was something on the roof so i trimmed back branches, scoured the roof and attic for loose items and then pinpointed the knocking pipe. It only occurs in the master shower. No other pipe makes a sound.

Comment: The pulsing in the PEX line may be coming from the water supply. Try turning off the water at the cutoff to the entire house and see if the pulsing changes. Also consider the possibility that you have a leak that is generating pulses of a frequency that the PEX is in resonance with. With all use in the house off (including the refrig ice maker) does the water meter advance?

Comment: I took your advice and shut the water off and was finally able to hear a very small leak outside and it does match the pulsing perfectly. Thank you for the help, it's greatly appreciated.

Comment: Fixed the leak and still have the pulsing issue. At this point I'm going to punch some holes in the wall where the noise is coming from to find out if there is anything going on in there.